# Add month and date (DATE_ADD) MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax-error

my query:

```
SELECT intern_id, date_add (pr_st_date, INTERVAL 8 month) as D_left
FROM interns;
```

Error: **You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') as D_left
FROM interns LIMIT 0, 25' at line 1**

Question: What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the space before the `(`.  Function calls need to have the parens next to the function name in MySQL:

```
SELECT intern_id, date_add(pr_st_date, INTERVAL 8 month) as D_left
FROM interns;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=53e6512189e98d80014831348397e4a6) is a db<>fiddle.

This is actually described in the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_ignore_space) (although it is not obvious where ;):

> IGNORE_SPACE
>
> Permit spaces between a function name and the ( character. This causes built-in function names to be treated as reserved words.

Note that `IGNORE_SPACE` is off by default, allowing collisions between function names and many keywords.

Comment: oh...
TY, my bad :)